# How to make decimal.Parse accept multiple cultures

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I need to accept 3 decimal data formats in my app:

- 123456,78 => 123456.78
- 123,456.78 => 123456.78
- 123456.78 => 123456.78

I cannot assume that one format will be used in particular situation. What I need is get a decimal value from a string no matter in which format it's given.

Is there a smart way to do this?

I was trying to use

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
```

but this doesn't seem to work on wp7.

So far I've done this:

```
public static class Extensions
{

    public static decimal toDecimal(this string s)
    {
        decimal res;

        int comasCount=0;
        int periodsCount=0;

        foreach (var c in s)
        {
            if (c == ',')
                comasCount++;
            else if (c == '.')
                periodsCount++;
        }

        if (periodsCount > 1)
            throw new FormatException();
        else if(periodsCount==0 && comasCount > 1)
            throw new FormatException();

        if(comasCount==1)
        {
            // pl-PL
            //parse here
        }else
        {
            //en-US
            //parse here
        }

        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: How tightly do you want to validate the input format?  For the particular formats given, one could use something like `s.Replace(",", s.Contains('.') ? "" : ".")` to convert the bottom formats to the top one, though some strings not meeting those formats (e.g. 12.345,67) might get converted to values that weren't what was intended (e.g. 12.34567 vs 12345.67).  Note also that if a decimal point (whether period or comma) is not required, the string "12,345" could be either 12.345 or 12345.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");` to create the culture.  Passing that culture to `decimal.Parse` or `decimal.TryParse` will parse the text appropriately for each culture.

Now, keep in mind that each culture may parse the text without failure but not parse it the way it's represented for the original culture.  For example `decimal.TryParse("1000,314", NumberStyles.Number, new CultureInfo("en-US"), out result)` will result success and 1000314m, not 1000.314m.  Whereas `decimal.TryParse("1000,314", NumberStyles.Number, new CultureInfo("fr-FR"), out result)` will result in 1000.314m.

Answer (score 2):

You might try something like this:

```
public static decimal ParseDecimalNumber( string s , string groupSeparators , string decimalPoints )
{
  NumberFormatInfo nfi   = (NumberFormatInfo) CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.Clone() ;
  NumberStyles     style = NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite
                         | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign
                         | NumberStyles.AllowThousands
                         | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint
                         | NumberStyles.AllowTrailingSign
                         | NumberStyles.AllowTrailingWhite
                         ;
  decimal          value ;
  bool             parsed = false ;

  for ( int i = 0 ; !parsed && i < groupSeparators.Length ; ++i )
  {

    nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = groupSeparators.Substring(i,1) ;

    for ( int j = 0 ; !parsed && j < decimalPoints.Length ; ++j )
    {
      if ( groupSeparators[i] == decimalPoints[j] ) continue ; // skip when group and decimal separator are identical

      nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = decimalPoints.Substring(j,1) ;

      parsed = Decimal.TryParse( s , style , nfi , out value ) ;

    }
  }

  if ( !parsed ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("s") ;

  return value ;

}
```

Usage is simple:

```
string groupSeparators = "., " ;
string decimalPoints   = ".,"  ;
Decimal value = ParseDecimalNumber( someStringContainingANumericLiteral , groupSeparators , decimalPoints ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Three calls to [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73) with different `NumberStyles` and `IFormatProvider` set to null should do it.